# Why my $state.go only working when inside a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to redirect the user when he types `/general` to `/boards`. I'm using `$state.go('boards')` to achieve that but it only works if I wrap it in a `setTimeout` function even with no delay.
Why is this behavior?

```
App.randomModule = angular.module('App.randomModule', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('general', {
      url: '/general', 
      resolve: {
        redirect: function ($state){

          // Working
          window.setTimeout(function(){
           $state.go('boards');
          }, 0); // Note there's no delay

          // Not working
          $state.go('boards');
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: I'd say that the timeout moves the callback to the end of the execution stack.

Comment: you're not returning anything for the `resolve`

Comment: What happens if it is not wrapped in `setTimeout`? Is there an error message?

Comment: I tried returning `true` but is not working neither. No, there's no error message if it's not inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: may be an  interceptor is a better way to go

Comment: resolve is for you to prepare some data to pass to your constructor. and only when this data is ready to go. i advice you to not use resolve in an unintended way.

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout(function(){}, 0)` executes the function in the next tick. And your resolve: redirect is not called until you do otherwise.

So while you're in the current loop, you tell ui-router: `$go('/general')` - so now it needs to go to general. But it will not do that right away, because it has a `resolve()`! First it tries to resolve the `redirect` object, then it will execute its' `$go('/general');`

So you have some changes stacked up for the digest cycle:
- create the resolve object (maybe you return a promise there, maybe a value, maybe undefined, does not matter)
- $state.go('/board')
- $state.go('/general')

And (assumption here), angular will see that it changes in the diggest cycle and it'll see that even if you call the resolve, it is not the last URL to be put and it gets overridden.

However, when you put the `setTimeout()` in play, your go('board') gets called *after* the digest loop, so it *will* execute.

On a side note, you might be better of using $timeout instead of setTimeout there.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to use `resolve` for this? Just inject `$urlRouterProvider` and set a redirection rule:

`$urlRouterProvider.when('/general', '/boards');`

Comment: I omitted the rest of the code inside the resolve to simplify it.

Comment: If this is conditional redirect (e.g. decision is made based on http response result) or just do-something-and-then-redirect, I'd go with moving all this logic into a controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ui-router events. There's $stateChangeStart to help you.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    // your logic
    if (...) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
})
```

Link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events